# How can I use a sprite for my jQuery datepicker icon?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datepicker

the ButtonImage is the property you specify for the icon but I want to use a sprite as the toggler - I can use buttonText and style the `<button>` element with a bg image but it probably wouldn't render properly in IE.. is there a way I can specify the exact HTML used for the button without having a button element rendered?

Comment: Argh, this would have been a good question to get answered.

Comment: @umassthrower I'm bringing this Q back from beyond the grave!

Comment: Oops, I forgot to put my solution when I solved this back in Dec, sorry everyone.  :-)  Thanks for your answer and reminding me though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

html:

```
<input class="date-picker" id="date"/><span class="icon">Hello</span>
```

js:

```
$(".icon").click(function(){
    $(".date-picker").focus();        
});
```

OR

```
$(".icon").click(function(){
    $(".date-picker").datepicker("show");        
});
```

to trigger the datepicker with arbitrary code. here's a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/qnA5R/)

Answer (score 2):

Ended up just specifying a png.